# Fork() does not create a child - C

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I'm working on a OS project on a Raspberry Pi 3B. I have to implement, in C, a sort of process-manager program. There is a main process **P** which has to handle a linked-list of processes **P1**-**P2**-**P3**-...-**PN**. (It's a chain of processes, meaning **P1** forks **P2**, **P2** forks **P3** and so on). The list is initialized with **P1**, a child of **P** as its first element.

On the hardware level there are 4 buttons (1,2,3,4) and 4 LEDs respectively and each couple is managed by an individual process **S**. These 4 **S** processes are also children of main process **P** but not in the linked-list. Now, each button has a different action that is performed on the list.

- Button 1 removes the first process in the list and shifts all
  following forward by one position. By shifting it's meant that the
  list of size *n* is emptied from *n* processes and then *n-1* are created
  and added back, simulating this way the removal of only the first process **P1** (they are indeed new processes).
- Button 2 adds a new process **PN+1** to the list.
- Button 3 select next process in the list (when the list is initialized, **P1** is selected by default).
- Button 4 removes selected process from the list (same story of button 2 but only the section selected-end of list is shifted).

I've implemented all the hardware part correctly, **P** and **S** processes communicate via pipes so that's out of the scope of this question. I've also managed to implement buttons 2 and 3 so that they satisfy the requirements.

I've been stuck for more than a week on how to implement button 1.

Here's *main.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "linkedlist.h"
#include "M_process.h"
#include "S_process.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char BUTTONS[] = "FASD";
    const int N_OF_S = 4;
    int fd1[2], fd2[2];  // pipes (P to S) and (S to P) 
    pid_t s_processes[N_OF_S];
    int arg_index = 1;
    setup_pipes(fd1, fd2);

    pid_t pid;
    for (int i = 0; i < N_OF_S; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in forking process S%d\n", i);
            return -1;
        } else if (pid > 0) {
            arg_index += 2;
            s_processes[i] = pid;
        } else {
            close(fd1[1]);
            close(fd2[0]);
            char *p;
            long button, led;
            button = strtol(argv[arg_index], &p, 10);
            led = strtol(argv[arg_index + 1], &p, 10);
            s_fun((int) button, (int) led, BUTTONS[i], fd1, fd2);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    close(fd1[0]);
    close(fd2[1]);

    List list;
    List *p_list = &list;
    initialize_list(p_list);

    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, listen_input, p_list);

    process_buttons(p_list);

    for (int i = 0; i < N_OF_S; i++) {
        waitpid(s_processes[i], NULL, 0);
    }

    wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

*M_process.c* (functions used in main process P):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "linkedlist.h"
#include "P_process.h"

int m_to_s[2];
int s_to_m[2];
int p_to_m[2];

void initialize_list(List *list) {
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    p_to_m[1] = fd[1];
    p_to_m[0] = fd[0];
    init_list(list);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't fork\n");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        close(m_to_s[1]);
        close(s_to_m[0]);
        close(fd[0]);
        signal(SIGINT, term_handler);
        signal(SIGUSR1, fork_handler);
        p_listen(1, fd);
        close(fd[1]);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        close(fd[1]);
        append(list, pid, "00000000");
    }
}

void *listen_input(void *list) {
    char input;
    int reading = 1;
    while (reading) {
        scanf(" %c", &input);
        switch (input) {
            case 'q':
                reading = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    write(m_to_s[1], &input, sizeof(char));
                }
                for (int i = size(list); i > 0; i--) {
                    kill(last_pid(list), SIGINT);
                    remove_last(list);
                }
                fprintf(stderr, "List deallocated.\n");
                break;
            case 'p':
                print_list(list);
                break;
            case 'h':
                fprintf(stderr, "Enter '\e[1;37mp\e[0m' to inspect the list or '\e[1;37mq\e[0m' to exit.\n");
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Command not found.\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Goodbye!\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int setup_pipes(int fd1[2], int fd2[2]) {
    if (pipe(fd1) < 0 || pipe(fd2) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in creating pipes\n");
        return -1;
    }
    m_to_s[1] = fd1[1];
    s_to_m[0] = fd2[0];
    return 0;
}

pid_t add_process(List *list, int n_of_processes) {
    if (n_of_processes > 0) {
        kill(last_pid(list), SIGUSR1);
        pid_t pid;
        read(p_to_m[0], &pid, sizeof(pid_t));
        char *p;
        p = id_generator(8);
        append(list, pid, p);
        add_process(list, n_of_processes - 1);
        return pid;
    }
    return 0;
}

void process_buttons(List *list) {
    char cmd;
    while (read(s_to_m[0], &cmd, sizeof(char)) != 0) {
        switch (cmd) {
            case 'F': {
                pid_t removed = first_pid(list);
                int to_add = size(list) - 1;
                for (int i = size(list); i > 0; i--) {
                    kill(last_pid(list), SIGINT);
                    remove_last(list);
                }
                initialize_list(list);
                add_process(list,to_add);
                fprintf(stderr, "(\e[1;31m-\e[0m) First process (\e[1;37m%d\e[0m) removed.\n", removed);
                break;
            }
            case 'A': {
                pid_t pid = add_process(list, 1);
                fprintf(stderr, "(\e[1;32m+\e[0m) Process \e[1;37m%d\e[0m [id: %s] appended to the list.\n", pid,
                        last_id(list));
                break;
            }
            case 'S': {
                select_next(list);
                fprintf(stderr, "(\e[1;33m*\e[0m) Next process (\e[1;37m%d\e[0m) selected.\n", selected_pid(list));
                break;
            }
            case 'D': {
                fprintf(stderr, "(\e[1;31m-\e[0m) Removed selected process (\e[1;37m%d\e[0m) from the list.\e[0m\n",
                        selected_pid(list));
                break;
            }
            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally *P_process.c* (with functions used by processes P in the list):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int fd[2];
int listen;

void p_listen(int l, int fd3[2]) {
    fd[0] = fd3[0];
    fd[1] = fd3[1];
    listen = l;
    while (listen) pause();
}

void fork_handler(int signo) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't add another P");
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        write(fd[1], &pid, sizeof(pid_t));
    }
}

void term_handler(int signo) {
    listen = 0;
}
```

In practice, processes in the list do nothing but wait for a signal, then they either exit or fork. The linked-list is implemented in another file, you can assume its basic and common functions.

The ideas behind my implementation are basically the following:

- If I need to add a process **PN+1**, I sent a **SIGUSR1** signal to
  the last process **PN** in list which calls the *fork_handler* function. **PN** forks,
  sends through a pipe the pid of **PN+1** to main process **P** which adds him
  to the list. **PN+1** is now the last in the list and waits for a signal (this works as intended).
- Removing the first and reconstruct the list of *n-1* processes is where I'm stuck. Basically I memorize *n*, I send a **SIGINT** signal to each process **P** in the list and remove them from the list. Everything works fine until this point. I have an empty list that I have to repopulate with **n-1** processes. So I re-initialize the list (adding a process **P1** the same way it was added at the start of the whole program) and then add the *n-2* remaining.

An example of an output is:

```
p
Process list: 30594
(+) Process 30611 [id:pkDHTxmM] appended to the list.
(+) Process 30612 [id:R18N2l9k] appended to the list.      // Pressed four times
(+) Process 30615 [id:88EmLgN7] appended to the list.      // button 2
(+) Process 30616 [id:cCCTt9rW] appended to the list.
p
Process list: 30594 -> 30611 -> 30612 -> 30615 -> 30616
(-) First process (30594) removed.                         // Pressed once first button
p
Process list: 30619 -> 7 -> 6370080 -> 6370120
```

The task manager shows now only the main process **P** and the four **S** processes.
After a lot of checks I found out that the forking in the *initialize_list()* function in *M_process.c* does not work. The main process receives a new pid from *fork()* and in fact that pid is added to the list (30619 in the output example), but actually there is no existing process with that pid. It is not even the case that it gets created and immediately quits, since I tried to put a print statement in the **pid == 0** branch and nothing happened. It does work as intended though when there's only one element **P1** in the list (another thing that I can't explain myself).

I really don't see why the *fork()* call returns a pid to main process **P** but wouldn't actually create a child with that pid, that seems to be the issue that keeps me from going on with the project.

(I realize that everything it's kind of messy and maybe not so clear, but I found it very difficult to summarize what I need to accomplish and my current situation. Moreover, I realize that the way I posted this question doesn't allow you to test it, but since dealing also with a hardware part, I thought it would get even more complicated.)

Answer (score 0):

The `fork` in `initialize_list` does create a new process, but is is immediately killed by `kill` in `add_process` sending `SIGUSR1` before the signal handler is installed.

You could block the signal before `fork` then unblock it after installing the signal handler and in the parent, or just install the signal handler before calling `fork`.